# issue registering a EC2 instance with an Application Load Balancer (ALB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

According to the docs I should be able to register an EC2 instance with the [elb_instance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_instance_module.html#elb-instance-module) module, but the play fails with `ELB Staging1 does not exist`. For sanity check I've tried with the AWS CLI tool, but that fails with `An error occurred (LoadBalancerNotFound) when calling the RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer operation: There is no ACTIVE Load Balancer named 'Staging1'`. As a plot twist:

- AWS console shows the ALB as "Active"
- `elb_application_lb_facts` also lists it
- `ec2_elb_facts` does not list it (it only list classic ELBs that I have)

It seems like application load balancers are only supported in newer api version and the module or cli were not meant to work with it. However I cannot find an explicit mention that they should not work. I'm also aware of [`elbv2` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/index.html), but it doesn't seem to offer a way to register instances to an ELB.

**What am I missing here guys?**

Ansible task that I wrote:

```
- name: Register instances in the ALB
  local_action:
        module: elb_instance
        aws_access_key: "{{ aws_credentials.access_key_id }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_credentials.secret_access_key }}"
        region: "{{ aws_region }}"
        instance_id: "{{ item.instance_ids.0 }}"
        ec2_elbs: "Staging1"
        state: present
        wait: yes
  loop: "{{ new_instances.results }}"
```

alternative with `aws` cli tool (doesn't work either):

```
    - name: Register instance in ALB workaround
      command: "aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name Staging1 --instances {{ instance_ids | join(' ') }}"
      environment:
        AWS_REGION: "{{ aws_region }}"
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY: "{{ aws_credentials.access_key_id }}"
        AWS_SECRET_KEY: "{{ aws_credentials.secret_access_key }}"
```

Comment: I guess this shows that I didn't really read the application load balancer very well. There's not way to register with a ALB, because that's what the target groups are for. Oh well, it was a long day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elbv2 does offer a way to register targets to an elb. You do so by:

1. [Create a target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-target-group.html)
2. Then use the [Register target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/register-targets.html) API to register your EC2 instances
3. Then use the [Create Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/create-listener.html) API to associate the ELB with the target group

There are examples of doing this in the links I've provided.